# Perl equivalent to Php foreach loop

Tags: php, perl, foreach

I am looking for a Perl equivalent to the following php code:-

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
...
}
```

I know I can do a foreach loop like so:-

```
foreach my $array_value (@array){
..
}
```

Which will enable me to do things with the array values - but I would like to use the keys as well.

I know there is a Perl hash which allows you to set up key-value pairs, but I just want the index number that the array automatically gives you.

Answer (score 15):

If you're using Perl 5.12.0 or above you can use `each` on arrays:

```
my @array = 100 .. 103;

while (my ($key, $value) = each @array) {
    print "$key\t$value\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0       100
1       101
2       102
3       103
```

[perldoc each](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html)

Comment: Yes, the lazy `while` is preferable to the eager `foreach`.

Comment: @Axeman: That's a good point. Even if the performance gain is negligible on my four element array, it's certainly a noteworthy distinction.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
my @array=(4,5,2,1);
foreach $key (keys @array) {
    print $key." -> ".$array[$key]."\n";
}
```

Works for Hashes and Arrays.
In case of Arrays the $key holds the index.

Answer (score 7):

I guess the closest Perl is something like this:

```
foreach my $key (0 .. $#array) {
  my $value = $array[$key];

  # Now $key and $value contains the same as they would in the PHP example
}
```

Since Perl 5.12.0, you can use the [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) function on arrays as well as hashes. That might be a little more readable.

```
use 5.012;

foreach my $key (keys @array) {
  my $value = $array[$key];

  # Now $key and $value contains the same as they would in the PHP example
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all these answers.  My problem is solved!  I don't really want to vote on the best answer because they are all right.

Comment: If I was you, I'd accept flesk's answer. The `each` solution is closer the the PHP version than any of the other examples.